# monitoring mailscanner queue with zabbix

Tags: linux, monitoring, exim, zabbix, mailscanner

Anoyne knows how to setup zabbix monitoring for mailscanner queue ? 
We managed  to setup monitoring for exim  queue, but we noticed that mailscanner also fills its queue sometimes and we would like to be notified about that. e.g. when it reaches 200 emails.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.configserver.com/techfaq/faqlist.php?catid=5&faqid=14&page=1 claims that :
"To find out in shell how many mails are waiting to be processed by MailScanner, do:
exim -bpc"

You should probably add it as a Zabbix userparameter - or whichever way you did with exim queue.